# How to add markers in Map using latitude and longitude in ListView with qml

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to add markes into map by using the coordinates (latitude and longitude) specified in a listview. I could manage to write code for the list of coordinates and map working indivisually by following qt tutorials. But, still I don't have clear idea of connecting to the list to the map so that the list items are marked in the map.

my main.qml goes like this.

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6
ApplicationWindow {

ListModel {
    id: locationModel
    ListElement {
        lat: 0; lon: 0
    }
    ListElement {
        lat: 10; lon: 25
    }
}

ListView {
    id: listView
    clip: true

    model: locationModel
    delegate: listDelegate
    headerPositioning: ListView.OverlayHeader
    z: 2
    header: headerComponent
    focus: true
}

Rectangle {
x: 326
y: 400
width: 300
height: 300
visible: true

Plugin {
    id: mapPlugin
    name: "esri" // "mapboxgl", "esri", ...
    // specify plugin parameters if necessary
    // PluginParameter {
    //     name:
    //     value:
    // }
}

Map {
    id: place
    anchors.fill: parent
    plugin: mapPlugin
    center: QtPositioning.coordinate(0, 0)
    zoomLevel: 10
}
}
}
```

Comment: How the list should interact with the map? For what you need a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a MapItemView

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 500
    height: 500

    ListModel {
        id: locationModel
        ListElement {lat: 0; lon: 0; color: "blue"}
        ListElement {lat: 5; lon: 12.5; color: "green"}
        ListElement {lat: 10; lon: 25; color: "red"}
    }

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "esri"
    }

    Map {
        id: place
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(0, 0)
        zoomLevel: 5
        MapItemView
        {
            model: locationModel
            delegate: MapQuickItem {
                coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate(lat, lon)
                anchorPoint: Qt.point(10,10)
                sourceItem: Rectangle {
                    width: 20
                    height: 20
                    radius: 10
                    color: model.color
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it was very simple to follow and working. by the way, if I change ListElement by adding or removing dynamically, how can I make the Map can get notification and update it?

Comment: @Seong It will work automaticcaly, the model will inform the view of the modifications/